# Maximal value of autonomous DE at the endpoint of an interval of existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $E\subset R^n$ be open and $x_0\in E$. Suppose $f: E\rightarrow R^n$ with $f\in C^1(E)$, and $\left[0,\infty\right)$ is the right maximal interval of existence of the solution $x = \phi(t)$ to the IVP: $\dot{x} = f(x)$, $x(0) = x_0$. Given $y=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \phi(t)$ exists, prove that $f(y) = 0$.

**My question:** I tried to use contradiction by assuming that $f(y)\neq 0$, and considering the case when $f(y) < 0$ and $f(y) > 0$. I then tried to show that $f(y)$ is approaching either $\pm \infty$ corresponding to either case, which leads to the contradiction. But I'm still unsuccessful with this approach despite spending several hours to try to prove the contradiction.

Can someone help me with the contradiction proof above? The result is quite surprising, yet it's quite hard:p

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this difficult problem? I seriously got stuck on it, so please help if you can:(

Comment: @Evgeny: can you give this problem a try? I got stucked on it for several days:P